# Testing XML attributes in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

Suppose I have an XML and map

```
val xml = 
<a>
   <b x="x1" y="y1"/>
   <b x="x2" y="y2"/>
   <b x="x3" y="y3"/>
</a>

val m = Map("x1" -> "y1", "x2" -> "y2", "x3" -> "y3")
```

I am fetching `<b>` elements from XML and checking if the elements contain `x` and `y` attributes as in the map `m`.

```
val bs = xml \\ "b"
((bs \\ "@x").map(_.text) zip (bs \\ "@y").map(_.text)).toSet == m.toSet
```

The problems with this code:

- Code repetition
- `bs` passed twice
  etc.

How would you fix/improve this code ?

Comment: try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ErikAllik You are probably right but I prefer to keep all my programming questions in one account.

Comment: all stackexchange sites use the same login.

Comment: I see. Let's see if people answer it here. If they don't I will probably consider posting such questions on the "codereview" site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating a list of tuple, converting then to set:

```
scala> val m = Map("x1" -> "y1", "x2" -> "y2", "x3" -> "y3")
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(x1 -> y1, x2 -> y2, x3 -> y3)

scala> m.toSet
res56: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, String)] = Set((x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3))


scala> val m2 = bs map ( node => ( (node \\ "@x").text , (node \\ "@y").text  ))
m2: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[(String, String)] = List((x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3))

scala> m2.toSet
res57: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, String)] = Set((x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3))

scala> m.toSet == m2.toSet
res49: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Thanks. Creating a list of tuples first is better.

Comment: Or you can also create directly a Map. As you wish